# Find the min value & datetime for each day

Tags: postgresql, datetime, max, min, timescaledb

I have a timescaleDB database that has the following shape:

I have a temperature value each 5 minutes.

| dt | temperature |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-04-20 20:00:00 | 13 |
| 2019-04-20 20:05:00 | 12 |
| 2019-04-20 20:10:00 | 12 |

And I would like to get the **minimum temperature value for each day and display the exact datetime when it happened**. Another small constraint, in the case **I have two min temperature value for one day, I should select the earlier one of the day**.

The answer should look like this:

| dt | temperature |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-04-20 07:10:00 | 10 |
| 2019-04-21 04:35:00 | 5 |
| 2019-04-22 02:10:00 | 9 |

I already got something close to this, the only missing part is the exact dt, I just can get the date.

```
SELECT DATE(dt), temperature
FROM temperature_DB
GROUP BY CAST(dt as DATE)
```

Thank you in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DISTINCT ON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) syntax for that.
The requirement is to have a single value for a date, so DISTINCT ON (dt:date) should be used. Everything else is described in ORDER BY part of the statement.

```sql
SELECT 
  DISTINCT ON (dt::date)
  dt,
  temperature
FROM
  temperature_DB
ORDER BY
  dt::date,
  temperature ASC, -- (first value will be lowest)
  dt ASC --(put the earliest time of lowest temperature measurement first);
```